# Python input getting implicitly converted when the input length crosses 77 characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

The code which I am running takes an input from a file and reads it as a dataframe. Each line in the data file contains a long expression. for example, it looks roughly something like this (with about half a million more entries):

```
(((kshA-kslB)/(ZA*ZB))*abs((kshA/rdA)-(kshB/rpB)))  corr=      0.9514
(((eaA+kslB)+abs(eaA-eaB))/((ZA*rpB)*abs(rpB-rsB)))  corr=      0.9504
((abs(enA-enB)+abs(kslA-kslB))/((ZA*ZB)*(rpB*rsA)))  corr=      0.9502
```

I read each line of that dataframe and take the first column of it. Further, I convert it into a string (`f = str(df.iloc[i])` , `i` being the loop counter). [I need to do it as i will be using `eval()` to evaluate the string and also replace a few expressions.] Now, here I face two issues:

a. `f`, when printed gives an output like

```
0    (((eaA+kslB)+abs(eaA-eaB))/((ZA*rsB)*abs(rpB)))
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Cant I get the output with just expression [`(((eaA+kslB)+abs(eaA-eaB))/((ZA*rsB)*abs(rpB)))`] ? (I have no idea where the `0` comes from!)

b. Whenever the length of this output crosses 77 characters, it implicitly converts the expression into something like this `(((kshA-kslB)/(ZA*ZB))*abs((kshA/rdA)-(kshB/rp...` which gives me an error while evaluating it further.

Anyone has any idea where things are going wrong?

edit 1: This is what i get when i do df.head(). Note the ones ending with `...` are the one which have in excess of 77 characters.

```
0   (((eaA+kslB)+abs(eaA-eaB))/((ZA*rsB)*abs(rpB)))
1   (((kshA-kslB)/(ZA*ZB))*abs((kshA/rdA)-(kshB/rp...
2   (((eaA+kslB)+abs(eaA-eaB))/((ZA*rpB)*abs(rpB-r...
3   ((abs(enA-enB)+abs(kslA-kslB))/((ZA*ZB)*(rpB*r...
4   (((eaA*rdB)-(rsB*kshB))/((rpB)^3*(ZA*eaB)))
```

Comment: `df.iloc[row,column].str`

Comment: when i give `f= df.iloc[i,0].str` ,  it tells me `'str' object has no attribute 'str'
`. @wwii

Comment: Please include a minimal example of the df - `df.head()`. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: @wwii edited the question to include df.head().

Comment: `df.iloc[i].to_string(index=False)`

Comment: Or - `f = df.iloc[1].values[0]`

Comment: @wwii the first option works totally! did not try the second one. Thanks a ton! Any clue about the second issue in the question?

Comment: the second issue got resolved too! thanks for the link. :) @wwii